# Bash: Globbing behavior differences in different environments

Tags: bash, glob

I'm trying to learn some bash basics and ran into some unexpected behavior when echoing out some strings which can include "*" characters.  Now, I'm trying to understand when bash decides to glob outputs.

I can run type the following and execute it in bash:

```sh
foo="*"; echo $foo
```

Output: 
`*`

But then when I put the same code into a file, `printFoo.sh`, and execute:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo="*"; echo $foo
```

Output: `printFoo.sh foo.txt bar.txt`

How is the environment different when the command is run within a file that causes this difference in behavior?

My bash version is: GNU bash, version 3.2.57

Comment: There is a difference when you quote the variables.

Comment: @Jetchsisel : There is no difference in quoting between the two cases.  The OP used an unquoted `$foo` in both occasions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash does not behave differently with respect to globbing when used interactively or in a script. From your behaviour, I would rather conclude that your interactive shell is Zsh, since this is the only popular shell I am aware off which would behave in this way. Of course, if you wrote a zsh *script*, it would also not expand `$foo` in your example.

Comment: Got it.  I was using ZSH

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an almost identical version of bash but cannot reproduce your issue.  In other words, bash is behaving in the expected way for me:

```sh
$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
3.2.57(1)-release
$ foo="*"; echo $foo
bar.txt foo.txt printFoo.sh
```

I can only reproduce it if I quote foo in the echo command which gives the expected result of suppressing globbing:

```sh
$ foo="*"; echo "$foo"
*
```